# Общее название для твёрдых пластичных веществ

Tags: семантика

Каким существительным или прилагательным можно охарактеризовать такие субстанции, как масло, пластилин, тесто, которые ещё не являются отвердевшими, но представляют собой густой состав?

Comment: Мягкий, пластичный?

Comment: _Аморфные_ вещества (не имеют определённой температуры плавления и размягчаются постепенно с её изменением): http://www.yaklass.ru/materiali?chtid=371&mode=cht

Comment: @Alex_ander Можно ли так говорить о смесях (думаю, масло и тесто — вещества, а пластелин - смесь разных веществ)? Кстати, тесто с повышением температуры затвердевает, не так ли?

Comment: Думаю, что можно: это не о химическом составе вещества, а о его физическом (агрегатном) состоянии. Многие вещества существуют со своим описываемым свойством в ограниченном диапазоне температур, и тесто "затвердевает" в том же смысле, в каком пластилин испаряется при сильном нагреве или начинает быть хрупким при сильном охлаждении. Глина (которая относится к "формующимся массам") может со временем засохнуть и т. д. Мягкими и пластичными (в относительном смысле, не для рук человека) бывают металлы.

Answer (score 0):

Если позволите, — наречием: формующиеся (Ф. массы).

Comment: Еще можно сказать: конфо́рмные. Конфо́рмность — изменение в поведении или мнении человека под влиянием реального или воображаемого давления со стороны другого человека или группы людей

Answer (score 0):

Можно сказать "неэластически деформируемые тела".

Профессиональный материаловед может этим термином не удовлетвориться. Ибо с его точки зрения подобные материалы распадаются на две очень разные категории: вязкоэластические и вязкопластические. Но если не лезть в эти дебри, то термин "неэластически деформируемые тела" (или "неэластически деформируемые материалы") может считаться приемлемым.